# ERD Entity Relationship Diagram table

Tags: database, database-design, erd

I found this picture from database answers, it was made by Barry Williams.
Can someone explain what the REF_CONTACT_TYPES and CONTACTS tables are for? What's their purpose, because there's no relationship other than between themselves.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think these table are just for keeping records for that bookseller contacts.
May be that bookseller stores other bookseller/Publishers contacts in that tables.

Answer (score 0):

It's only guesswork to figure out Barry's model of the subject matter.  But I'll take a stab at it.  The missing relationship (junction table is you like) is Books-Contacts.  Meaning that, if you want to reach a contact about a given book, then this relationship will tell you which contacts to call.

It's unclear to me whether "customer" is a special subtype of "contect" or not.